# When is 2.8's release date and how to make it more stable

Tags: versions

Please who knows 2.8's release date. I can't wait for the stable version of 2.8, plus any tip to make it more stable is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update will be released in several steps. First, the Alpha on July 2nd, the Beta on August 12th, September 19 will finalize the Python API of Blender 2.8 and on October 20th you’ll get your hands on the first release candidate of Blender 2.8.
See more: https://80.lv/articles/the-release-date-of-blender-2-8-revealed/. I do not know if this info is outdated.

Comment: This is outdated information. At the time of writing, Nicola's dates are correct.

Answer (score 4):

On the 13th August (2018) **Blender 2.8 Alpha 2** was released. The Alpha status means that the software is still not stable, and a lot of effort is being put in dealing with crashes and instabilities, rather than new features.

On that day, the developers updated the previous roadmap. Now the plan is:

> - End of October: feature complete **Blender 2.80 Beta** at the Blender Conference.
> - Early 2019: **Blender 2.80 stable**.
> - 2019: Blender 2.81, 2.82, .. for features that didn’t make it in the first release.

(From [this blog post](https://code.blender.org/2018/08/blender-2-8-planning-update/))

There really aren't tips on how to make it more stable, as the possible reasons of instability are being investigated at the moment (that's the purpose of the Alpha). If you want to contribute to the roadmap and you are not a Blender developer, keep using it and testing it and submit crash reports to the bug tracker!

---

For updates I'd recommend following [the developers' blog](https://code.blender.org/) and [their video channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/BlenderCoders/videos).

Comment: Have in mind that all these dates are purely indicative and by no means set in stone. They are likely to change, and long delays are expected. Blender 2.8 will only release when it's ready™.

Answer (score 0):

Stable version is planned to be released on July/2019:

https://www.blender.org/2-8/#release-planning:-2.80-ready-in-july